# Highest resolution video possible on iphone6?

Tags: iphone, video

I would have thought that it would be possible to watch a 1920x1080 video on the iphone6.

But I was SHOCKED to see this in the UIKit:

iOS supports many industry-standard video formats and compression standards, including the following:

```
H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats

H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats

MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
```

Is 1920x1080 possible?  If so, why isn't apple screaming it from the rooftops?  Why are they topping out at 640x480 here in their specs?  Imagine an app that includes a 1920x1080 resolution video.  Can it be played on the iphone6?  If so, any ideas how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 6 can play up to AVC level 4.2. this tops at around 1920x1080 @ 64 fps. Or 16 fps at UHD resolutions.

http://www.apple.com/iphone-6/specs/

The resolutions in the OS document are values that EVERY iPhone can play. Not just the latest

Comment: Thanks!  

Can it do 1920x1080 at 25fps?